# Element wise multiplication of iterators and calculating sum

Tags: scala, elementwise-operations

Using two Lists, element wise multiplication of these lists and sum of resultant list can be calculated in following way.

```
(List1 , List2).zipped.foldLeft(0.0) { case (a, (b, c)) => a + b * c }
```

How can I preform this operation for two iterators in Scala in an optimal and fast way?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what is the question.

Comment: Write a benchmark, otherwise it's just guessing. Iterators might be fast because they could traverse the structure without calculating things twice, but I would avoid any statements about opimality of this or any other solution. Your current one might be close to "optiomal" or at least fast enough.

Comment: I am also a little bit confused. Apart from the performance part, both `zip` and `fold` are present on Iterators. Not sure what you found confusing about Iterators. The code would look almost identical. Did you implement that and weren't satisfied by it's performance?

Comment: what kind of performance improvement you are looking for memory(are those list are too big) or time complexity? your current implementation look good enough.

Comment: @sinanspd I used aboove code and provide Iterator instead of List. But that code is not working

Comment: @RamanMishra Time complexity

Answer (score 2):

```
(iterator1 zip iterator2).foldLeft(0.0) { case (a, (b, c)) => a + b * c }
```

is okay I suppose. If you want to squeeze the last bit of performance out of it, use arrays and a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code that should work with any collection and any numeric type.
It tries to be efficient by doing everything in one traversal. However, as @Martijn said, if you need it to be the most efficient solution then just use plain **Arrays** of a primitive type like **Int** or **Double** and a `while`.

```
def dotProduct[N : Numeric](l1: IterableOnce[N], l2: IterableOnce[N]): N =
  l1.iterator.zip(l2).map {
    case (x, y) => Numeric[N].times(x, y)
  }.sum
```

*(note: this code is intended for `2.13+`, for `2.12-` you may use **Iterable** instead of **IterableOnce**)*